# How to convert an sql "with" so that it does not use "with"

Tags: sql, where-clause, common-table-expression

I need to rewrite the below query which uses "with" so that it no longer uses "with", but I am not sure how to do it exactly. I was told to use sub queries, but my attempt did not work.

The below is what I need to convert:

```
with
best (cid, title, year, lowest) as (
    select distinct M.cid, O.title, O.year, min(price)
        from yrb_member M, yrb_purchase P, yrb_offer O
        where M.club = O.club and
              M.cid = P.cid and
              P.title = O.title and P.year = O.year
        group by M.cid, O.title, O.year
)
select C.name, P.title, P.year, qnty, price, lowest
from yrb_customer C, yrb_purchase P, Best B, yrb_offer O
where P.cid = B.cid and P.title = B.title and
      P.year = B.year and P.title = O.title and
      P.year = O.year and P.club = O.club and
      C.cid = P.cid and
      O.price > B.lowest
order by C.name, P.title, P.year;
```

I tried copying parts of the with statement into the where statement, but I received an error saying "The result of a scalar fullselect, SELECT INTO statement, or VALUES INTO statement is more than one row." You can see my attempt below (it still uses "with", but I was trying to replace a small portion to see if I can use the same technique on the rest of the query to ultimately remove the "with" statement entirely):

```
with
best (cid, title, year, lowest) as (
    select distinct M.cid, O.title, O.year, min(price)
        from yrb_member M, yrb_purchase P, yrb_offer O
        where M.club = O.club and
              M.cid = P.cid and
              P.title = O.title and P.year = O.year
        group by M.cid, O.title, O.year
)
select distinct C.name, P.title, P.year, qnty, price, lowest
from yrb_customer C, yrb_purchase P, Best B, yrb_offer O
where P.cid =

(select distinct M.cid
        from yrb_member M, yrb_purchase P, yrb_offer O
        where M.club = O.club and
              M.cid = P.cid and
              P.title = O.title and P.year = O.year
        )

and P.title = B.title and
      P.year = B.year and P.title = O.title and
      P.year = O.year and P.club = O.club and
      C.cid = P.cid and
      O.price > B.lowest
order by C.name, P.title, P.year;
```

Comment: Hello! i'd like you to meet a friend of mine, his name is `join`. check out his profile: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191472(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Simply say "no" to commas in the `from` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which database you are using, but you can normally just move the query from the `with` directly into the `from` clause of your query.  Like this:

```
select C.name, P.title, P.year, qnty, price, lowest
from yrb_customer C, yrb_purchase P, 
(
    select distinct M.cid, O.title, O.year, min(price)
        from yrb_member M, yrb_purchase P, yrb_offer O
        where M.club = O.club and
              M.cid = P.cid and
              P.title = O.title and P.year = O.year
        group by M.cid, O.title, O.year
) B, 
yrb_offer O
where P.cid = B.cid and P.title = B.title and
      P.year = B.year and P.title = O.title and
      P.year = O.year and P.club = O.club and
      C.cid = P.cid and
      O.price > B.lowest
order by C.name, P.title, P.year;
```